# How do you stop the browser from changing the domain name to the ip address?

Tags: dns, apache2, ip-address

I've recently acquired a domain name for my website, but when I enter the URL in a browser it get's instantly converted to the webserver's ip-address. How is it possible to keep showing the domain name?

The website is set up on a ubuntu server using apache2. Virtual hosting is enabled.

Comment: Please add more detail - is it the same on all browsers(Chrome, Brave, Edge etc) .  Does it still happen if you browse on mobile?

Comment: Which CMS are you using? If you're using WordPress or something similar, then it's a redirect "feature" in the code that you will need to update. If you're using straight HTML files for a static site, then there may be a redirect as part of your `.htaccess` file.